# python ctypes pointer arithmetic

Tags: python, ctypes

Is it possible with ctypes to make pointer arithmetic?

First, let me show you what I'm trying to do in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo {
 short *Bar;
 short *end_Bar;
};

int main() {
  short tab[3] = {1,2,3};
  struct Foo foo;
  foo.Bar = tab;
  foo.end_Bar = foo.Bar + 2; // Pointer arithmetic
  short *temp = foo.Bar;
  while(temp != foo.end_Bar)
    printf("%hi", *(temp++));
  printf("%hi", *(foo.end_Bar));
  return 0;
}
```

Now you understand that what I'm doing is creating an array of integer, and keeping in reference **two pointers in a structure**. One pointer at the begining and one at the end, **instead** of keeping the first pointer and the length of the array.

Now in Python I have an object that inherit from **ctypes.Structure** and as two members which are **ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_short)** type.

```
import ctypes

class c_Foo(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
       ("Bar", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_short)),
       ("end_Bar", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_short))
    ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tab = [1,2,3]
    foo = c_Foo()
    foo.Bar = (c_short * len(tab))(*tab)
    foo.end_Bar = foo.Bar + 2 # TypeError, unsupported operand
```

So now the question. Is it **possible to do pointer arithmetic** with ctypes? I know that you can access value of the array by it index, but I don't want that, because **I don't want a length reference in my structure**.

Comment: Why? What do you gain by doing this?

Comment: It's not about why, but how. This is a simple example to demonstrate what I want, not what I do.

Comment: I disagree... this seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/344593) to me.

Comment: How is this related to the C language? How you do something in C is completely irrelevant how to do it in Python. I agree with @TemporalWolf: This is an XY problem.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic isn't implemented, but you can index a pointer. The problem here is that this calls the getfunc, which for a simple type such as `c_short` automatically converts the indexed value to a Python integer. This behavior is disabled for subclasses of simple types, since it's assumed that you need to preserve the derived type. So if use a subclass of `c_short`, then you could use `ctypes.pointer(foo.Bar[2])`. There are other options, but it gets increasingly cumbersome.

Comment: I'm doing a wrapper around C.
In one of my C function, it use two pointers for an array (yes, useless but that is not the point here). So I need to create this array in Python, reference two pointers of this array in a Python Structure, and send it to the C lib. Now, if it's impossible, I'll use the single pointer with length. Is is more clear?

Comment: Work great @eryksun thank you!

Answer (score 7):

It's convoluted, but this computes a `c_short` object at a byte offset in `tab`  that shares its buffer, then gets a pointer to it:

```
from ctypes import *

class c_Foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
       ("Bar", POINTER(c_short)),
       ("end_Bar", POINTER(c_short))
    ]

tab = (c_short*3)(1,2,3)
foo = c_Foo()
foo.Bar = tab
foo.end_Bar = pointer(c_short.from_buffer(tab,sizeof(c_short)*2))
print(tab[2])
print(foo.Bar[2])
print(foo.end_Bar[0])
tab[2] = 4
print(tab[2])
print(foo.Bar[2])
print(foo.end_Bar[0])
```

> ```
> 3
> 3
> 3
> 4
> 4
> 4
> ```

Comment: I think the next step for me, if using a subclass of `c_short` isn't an option, would be to use a pointer to a unit-length array, e.g. `foo.end_Bar = POINTER(tab._type_ * 1)(tab)[2]`. If `tab` is no longer available you can use `foo.end_Bar = POINTER(foo.Bar._type_ * 1)(foo.Bar.contents)[2]`.